# React Native Signature Pad V2 - TypeError: Cannot convert null value to object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, signaturepad

After upgrading my Expo app to
"expo": "^49.0.0"
"react-native": "0.72.3",
"react-native-signature-pad-v2": "1.1.0"

I get the error:

TypeError: Cannot convert null value to object

This error is located at:
in Unknown (created by SignaturePad)
in SignaturePad (created by SignatureScreen)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by SignatureScreen)
in SignatureScreen (created by Connect(SignatureScreen))
in Connect(SignatureScreen) (created by SceneView)
in StaticContainer

When loading the signature pad.

How do I solve this?